# Error en DataTable Jquery "Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. "

Tags: php, jquery, html, mariadb

Buenas gente, se me ha presentado este error y no he podido solucionarlo, espero puedan ayudarme:

Este es mi código de PHP en el cual obtengo mis registros de la DB

```
include ("conexion.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM ciclos;";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

if (!$resultado){
    die("Error");       
}else{
    $array["data"] = []; 
    while( $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        $arreglo["data"][] =  array_map("utf8_encode",$data);
    }
    echo json_encode($arreglo);
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Este es mi código que tengo en el HTML:

```
<script>        
    $(document).on("ready", function(){
        listar();
    });
    var listar = function(){
        var table = $("#ciclos").DataTable({
            "ajax":{
                "method":"POST",
                "url": "listar.php"
            },
            "colums":[
                {"data":"ciclo"},
                {"data":"fecha_inicio"},                    
                {"data":"fecha_termino"}
            ],
            "language" : idioma_espaniol
        });
    }
    var idioma_espaniol = {
"sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
"sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
"sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
"sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
"sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
"sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
"sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
"sInfoPostFix":    "",
"sSearch":         "Buscar:",
"sUrl":            "",
"sInfoThousands":  ",",
"sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
"oPaginate": {
    "sFirst":    "Primero",
    "sLast":     "Último",
    "sNext":     "Siguiente",
    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
},
"oAria": {
    "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
}
}       

</script>
```

Codigo HTML de la tabla:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div id="cuadro1" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
            <h3 class="text-center"> <small class="mensaje"></small></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive col-sm-12">        
            <table id="ciclos" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ciclo</th>
                        <th>Fecha de Termino</th>
                        <th>Fecha de Inicio</th>                            
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>                    
            </table>
        </div>          
    </div>      
</div>
```

El archivo listar.php muestra los datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mensaje que arroja es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al llamar a `listar.php` directamente desde tu explorador, ¿Te muestra un objeto JSON u otro mensaje?. Si es un objeto JSON, podrías indicarnos cual es.

Comment: Me arroja los datos que pido de mi DB, ya actualice la publicación

Comment: Falta agregar también la declaración HTML de tu tabla, elemento `table` con id `ciclos`.

Comment: Ya agregue el código de la tabla a la publicación

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta lo que te aparece en la pestaña *Red* (o *Network*) de *DevTools*? Específicamente el detalle de la solicitud *AJAX* a  *listar.php*.

Comment: Ya agregue la imagen del error que me arroja, despues de eso me muestra que se estan mostrando los registros pero no estan en la tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando se usa la opción `columns` tenes que asegurarte de tener el mismo número de columnas en el archivo `JavaScript` y en la tabla `HTML`.

La solución a este problema puede ser:

- agregar/quitar un objeto `data`, o
- agregar/quitar la celda de cabecera `<th>` de la tabla

dependiendo de si está faltando o está sobrando uno de estos elementos.

Además, en el inicio de tu archivo `PHP` podrías indicar que la respuesta utiliza el formato `JSON` modificando la cabecera `HTTP` con la siguiente línea:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Ya corregi y hice cambios pero sigue sin darme resultados..

Comment: @MiguelAngel En la opción `columns` te falta la letra `n`